# Combining results of 2 Queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

Good day ,
I am new to this forum and i am glad as i am new to Sql.
How can i combine the results of these two queries either using Union all or by any means.Sorry query A is to long

**Query
(A)**

```
select 
    a.SiteName,
    a.Hostname,
    a.FreeSpace,
    a.FreeSpacePerc,
    a.Color,
    b.TotalMemory,
    a.Createdon,
    'ProLiant DL585 G7' as Model

from
(
SELECT 
    [SiteName],
    [Hostname],
    [SystemDriveName] as DriveName,
    cast([SystemFreeSpace] as nvarchar(10)) + ' GB (' + [SystemDriveName] + ':)' as FreeSpace,
    cast(([SystemFreeSpacePercentage]*100) as nvarchar(10)) + '% (' + [SystemDriveName] + ':)' as FreeSpacePerc,
    case when [SystemFreeSpace] <= 20 then 'RED' else 'BLACK' end as Color,
    Createdon
  FROM [RednaDBA].[dbo].[HostDriveStatus]
  where 
    active = 1 and
    Hostname like 'AC%'and Createdon >= DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day,0,GETDATE()),0)

union   
select * from
(   
SELECT 
    [SiteName],
    [Hostname],
    [DataDriveName],
    cast([DataFreeSpace] as nvarchar(10)) + ' GB (' + [DataDriveName] + ':)' as FreeSpace,
    cast(([DataFreeSpacePercentage]*100) as nvarchar(10)) + '% (' + [DataDriveName] + ':)' as FreeSpacePerc,
    case when [DataFreeSpace] <= 20 then 'RED' else 'BLACK' end as Color,
    CreatedOn
  FROM [RednaDBA].[dbo].[HostDriveStatus]
  where 
    active = 1 and
    Hostname like 'AC%'and Createdon >= DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day,0,GETDATE()),0)

union
SELECT 
    [SiteName],
    [Hostname],
    [BackupDriveName],
    cast([BackupFreeSpace] as nvarchar(10)) + ' GB (' + [BackupDriveName] + ':)' as FreeSpace,
    cast(([BackupFreeSpacePercentage]*100) as nvarchar(10)) + '% (' + [BackupDriveName] + ':)' as FreeSpacePerc,
    case when [BackupFreeSpace] <= 20 then 'RED' else 'BLACK' end as Color,
    Createdon
  FROM [RednaDBA].[dbo].[HostDriveStatus]
  where 
    active = 1 and
    Hostname like 'AC%'and Createdon >= DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day,0,GETDATE()),0)

    Union
SELECT 
    [SiteName],
    [Hostname],
    [Backup2DriveName],
    cast([Backup2FreeSpace] as nvarchar(10)) + ' GB (' + [Backup2DriveName] + ':)' as FreeSpace,
    cast(([Backup2FreeSpacePercentage]*100) as nvarchar(10)) + '% (' + [Backup2DriveName] + ':)' as FreeSpacePerc,
    case when [BackupFreeSpace] <= 20 then 'RED' else 'BLACK' end as Color,
    CreatedOn
  FROM [RednaDBA].[dbo].[HostDriveStatus]
  where 
    active = 1 and
    Hostname like 'AC%'and Createdon >= DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day,0,GETDATE()),0)


) as a
) as a
join 
(
SELECT
    [SiteName],
    [Hostname],
    [TotalMemory] + ' GB' as TotalMemory,
    Createdon
  FROM [RednaDBA].[dbo].[HostMemoryCPUStatus]
  where 
    active = 1 and
    Hostname like 'AC%'and Createdon >= DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day,0,GETDATE()),0)

) as b on a.SiteName = a.SiteName and a.Hostname = b.Hostname
 order by
    a.[SiteName], DriveName
```

---

**Query
(B)**

```
SELECT  
    [SiteName],
    [Hostname],
    cast([SystemFreeSpace] as nvarchar(10)) + ' GB (' + [SystemDriveName] + ':)' as FreeSpace,
    cast(([SystemFreeSpacePercentage]*100) as nvarchar(10)) + '% (' + [SystemDriveName] + ':)' as FreeSpacePerc,
    case when [SystemFreeSpace] <= 20 then 'RED' else 'BLACK' end as Color,
     cast([Memory] as nvarchar(10)) + ' GB ' as TotalMemory,
    Createdon,
    'ProLiant DL585 G7' as Model
  FROM [RednaDBA].[dbo].[DriveStatus_Solarwinds]
  where 
    Hostname like 'AC%'and Createdon >= DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day,0,GETDATE()),0)
```

Comment: Show us what you already tried and what is not working. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If those two queries were written by you, I see no reason why you wouldn't be able to join the results of A and B together with a UNION yourself, seeing as there are multiple UNION uses in Query (A) already. Otherwise, your best bet would be to read the MSDN description of UNION here to get an idea of how to go about it https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx